# Owl Carousel image not displaying on foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-7

i tried to add owl carousel in laravel project but when i add it to foreach the image is not showing. if the image is static it can appear. [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Ap6.png)

This my code

```
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">                       
                    @php
                        $incrementCategory = 0
                    @endphp
                    @forelse ( $categories as $category )                                                                                                                                                
                        <div
                            class="col-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2"
                            data-aos="fade-up"
                            data-aos-delay="{{ $incrementCategory += 100 }}"
                        >
                         <a href="{{ route('categories-detail', $category->slug) }}" 
                          class="component-categories d-block">

                                <div class="categories-image">
                                    <img
                                        src="{{ Storage::url($category->photo) }}"
                                        alt=""
                                        class="w-100"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <p class="categories-text">{{ $category->name }}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                                                                            
                    @empty
                        <div class="col-12 text-center py-5" 
                            data-aos="fade-up"
                            data-aos-delay="100">
                            Category not found
                        </div>                                
                    @endforelse                                                                     
                </div>
```

This my Script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.green.min.css"/>
```

This Javascript

```
<script>  $(document).ready(function($){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  margin:10,
  nav:false,
  autoWidth:false,
  responsive:{0:{items:1},600:{items:3},1000:{items:5}}
})
})
</script>
```

This my controller for store

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{
    $data= $request->all();

    $data['slug'] = Str::slug($request->name);
    $data['photo'] = $request->file('photo')->store('assets/category','public');

    Category::create($data);

    return redirect()->route('category.index');
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you run php artisan storage:link

Comment: @Amir it's done but still nothing

Comment: Could you post the image upload method

Comment: @Amir i use this [link](https://pastebin.com/yC8ErkYc)

Comment: I meant the image upload in the controller

Comment: @Amir i have done update it in my post

Comment: well, I tried to re-create it and it works fine.

Comment: @Amir what problem with my device XD, thnk for your time